# Soft input keyboard not visible in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, window-managers, android-windowmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

I used the following code to hide the default keyboard to bring up my own and it works fine

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

But now when I use the following on the click of a button, the soft keyboard does not reappear. Why?

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```